# Topologies for hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In what topologies we can make hadoop cluster? Currently only running with tree structure,single master and multiple slaves. Am looking for more variants like multiple master etc.

Comment: btw, noticed that your questions are really vague. let us know ur requirements, any research done.

Comment: In which was we can arrange hadoop cluster , like i need to masters and if one fails other will take over else both of them will work together and synch data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting, after seeing the question for any tool or framework which provides multiple masters in Hadoop.  But, i didn't find one.

Coming to hadoop, NameNode (Master) - Multiple DataNodes (Slaves), so according to hadoop's design perceptive this fair enough.

But, their is another addition to the NameNode called as secondary namenode, did n't think about it as a another master. refer here http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/multi-host-secondarynamenode-configuration/